# jquery: scroll effect?

Tags: jquery, html

I got the problem Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined .

how about href="index.html#section2"?

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
```

scrollEffect();
 });

```
<nav id="top-header-wrapper">
<div id="nav-link">
    <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section2">about</a>
    <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section3">portfolio</a>
    <a class="click-link" href="index.html#section4">contact</a>
</div>
```

```
function scrollEffect() {
$('#nav-link a').click(function(){
     $('html,body').animate({
    scrollTop: $($(this).attr('href')).offset().top
}, 'slow');
return false;
});
```

}

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
scrollTop: $(($(this).attr('href')).substring(10)).offset().top
```

which should remove the `index.html` part of the string and link correctly to just `#section2`.

Comment: I did. it works. but i have to link to index.html#section2 because i have to click to another page.